# min() function, but retrieve different values

Tags: php, string-comparison, min

Is there some way to retrieve different values with the `min()` function?

> **EDIT**

`min()` works in such a way that it returns values used in the argument list, I need other values to be returned, connected with the input arguments.

```
$string1 = 'This a longer string';
$string2 = 'Short string';

$string_value1 = 320;
$string_value2 = 170;

min($string_value1, $string_value2);    // I want it to return $string2, because it has the lowest value
```

Comment: `$shortestlength = min(array_map('strlen', array($string1, $string2)));`

Comment: @MarkBaker See my edit, I'm not interested in the length

Comment: If you mean you want $string2 returned because $string_value2 has the lowest value; what is the relationship between $string2 and $string_value2 (other than a human-readable name)?

Comment: now your question makes little sense. you need to link your two sets of data (strings and numerical values) together somehow. probably an associative array with the strings as keys.

Comment: see my updated answer ... i think that's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't change the behavior of `min` or other native PHP functions. But if I understand your question correctly, you don't need to. Try something like this:

```
$string_value1 = 320;
$string_value2 = 170;

$string1 = 'This a longer string';
$string2 = 'Short string';

#first link your numbers and strings together by using an array
$strings = array(
    $string_value1 => $string1,
    $string_value2 => $string2
);

#determine the lowest "string value"
$lowest_index = min($string_value1, $string_value2);

#get the string associated with this value
echo $strings[$lowest_index];         #prints "Short string"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

Simple Example :

```
$strings = [
        'This a longer string',
        'Short string'
];

echo array_reduce($strings, function ($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) > strlen($a) ? $a : $b;
});
```

If you need to also compare other types .. then you can use

Example 1

```
$string1 = 'This a longer string';
$string2 = 'Short string';
$string3 = 'Hello';
 echo minLength($string1, $string2 , $string3);
```

Output

```
Hello
```

Example 2

```
$range = range(170, 320);
shuffle($range);            // Shuffle the array 
echo minLength($range);
```

Output

```
170
```

Function Used

```
function minLength() {
    $parse = function ($v) {
        if (is_int($v) || is_float($v)) {
            return $v;
        } elseif (is_string($v)) {
            return strlen($v);
        } elseif (is_object($v) || is_array($v)) {
            return count($v);
        } else {
            return $v;
        }
    };

    $args = (func_num_args() === 1 && is_array(func_get_arg(0)))
             ? func_get_arg(0) : func_get_args();

    return array_reduce($args, function ($a, $b) use($parse) {
        return $parse($b) > $parse($a) ? $a : $b;
    }, reset($args));
}
```

Comment: No. Try print min('aaaaaaaaaa','b');

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that enough in your own function?

```
if(strlen($string1) < strlen($string2)) {
    return $string1;
} else {
    return $string2;
}
```

Comment: or just strlen($string1) <= strlen($string2) ? $string1 : $string2;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string1 = 'This a longer string';
$string2 = 'Short string';

$strings = array($string1, $string2);
$length = array();
$smallest = '-N/A-';

foreach ($strings as $k=>$v)
{
    $length[$k] = strlen($v);
}

$min = min($length);
foreach ($strings as $k=>$v)
{
    if ($length[$k] === $min)
    {
        $smallest = $v;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can add as many values as you want to the array and it will return the string with the smallest number of characters. If there are multiple strings that match the smallest number of characters, the first one will be returned. The variable $smallest will end up containing the smallest string.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with multiple values:

```
<?php
$array = array("Short string", "This a longer string", "This is an even longer string");
$longest = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if($i > 0)
    {
        if(strlen($array[$i]) > strlen($array[$longest]))
        {
        $longest = $i;
        }
    }
}
echo $array[$longest]; //outputs "This is an even longer string"
?>
```